# Finding subsets of lenght n of array (given set) - Pascal

Tags: pascal

Given a set {1,2,3,4,5...n} of n elements, we need to find all subsets of length k .

For example, if n = 4 and k = 2, the output would be {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}.

Please, I know that I have to do it with recursion but I dont know how to start... Can anybody help me how to do it in Pascal?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Interested by myself, here the code in Free Pascal:

```
PROGRAM SubSets;

USES
   SysUtils;

TYPE
   TSubArray = ARRAY OF Integer;

PROCEDURE PrintSet(SubSet : TSubArray);

VAR
   i : Integer;
   h : Integer;

BEGIN
   h := High(SubSet);
   Write('{');
   FOR i := 0 TO h DO
   BEGIN
      Write(SubSet[i]);
      IF i < h THEN Write(',');        
   END;
   Write('} ');
END;

PROCEDURE FindSets(Start, Stop, Pos : Integer; SubSet : TSubArray);

VAR
   i : Integer;
   HighIndex : Integer;
   MaxFirst  : Integer;

BEGIN
   HighIndex := High(SubSet);
   IF Pos = HighIndex THEN
   BEGIN
      FOR i := Start TO Stop DO
      BEGIN
         SubSet[Pos] := i;
         PrintSet(SubSet);
      END;
   END ELSE BEGIN
      MaxFirst := Stop - (HighIndex - Pos);    
      FOR i := Start TO MaxFirst DO
      BEGIN
         SubSet[Pos] := i;
         FindSets(i+1, Stop, Pos+1, SubSet);
      END;
   END;
   WriteLn;
END;

VAR
   k, n   : Integer;
   SubSet : TSubArray;

BEGIN
   IF ParamCount = 2 THEN
   BEGIN
      k := StrToInt(ParamStr(1));
      n := StrToInt(ParamStr(2));
      SetLength(SubSet, n);
      FindSets(1, k, 0, SubSet);
   END;
END.
```

And some output:

```
C:\Users\Kitana>subsets 6 3
{1,2,3} {1,2,4} {1,2,5} {1,2,6}
{1,3,4} {1,3,5} {1,3,6}
{1,4,5} {1,4,6}
{1,5,6}

{2,3,4} {2,3,5} {2,3,6}
{2,4,5} {2,4,6}
{2,5,6}

{3,4,5} {3,4,6}
{3,5,6}

{4,5,6}



C:\Users\Kitana>
```